# How do i insert a multidimensional array into a cakephp 2.2.1 database?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

i have three tables an i would insert one array to the database. Its one tv show, with many seasons. And the Seasons have many Episodes. Here are my tables:

**shows**

```
id
title
created
modified
```

**seasons**

```
id
shows_id
created
modified
```

**episodes**

```
id
seasons_id
title
created
modified
```

The Model files:

**Show.php**

```
<?php
class Show extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Show';
    public $hasMany = 'Season';
}
```

**Season.php**

```
<?php
class Season extends AppModel {
    public $name        = 'Season';
    public $belongsTo   = 'Show';
    public $hasMany     = 'Episode';
}
```

**Episode.php**

```
<?php
class Episode extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Episode';
    public $belongsTo = 'Season';
}
```

I had tried it with this Array:

```
$this->Show->create();

$sql_show = array(
    'Show' => array(
        'id'        => 2,
        'title'     => 'Super Mega Show',
    ),
    'Season' => array(
        array(
            'id'        => 1,
            'shows_id'  => 2,
            'Episode'   => array(
                array(
                    'id'    => 1,
                    'title' => 'Episode Title 1'
                ),
                array(
                    'id'    => 2,
                    'title' => 'Episode Title 2 '
                ),
                array(
                    'id'    => 3,
                    'title' => 'Episode Title 3'
                ),
            )
        ),
    )
);


$this->Show->saveAll($sql_show);
```

How can i insert this array?

greetings

Comment: Tried `serialize`?

EDIT: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you wanted.

Comment: I would use two tables for this purpose, `shows` and `episodes`, otherwise you have to add `parent_id` to your table, where `parent_id=0` is a show and `parent_id=N` is episode of the show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code to save multiple associated data:

```
 $this->Show->save($sql_show, array('deep' => true));
```

You can also try it using [saveAssociated()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) method.

kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: YESS!! It works! thank you very much :)

`$this->Show->save($sql_show, array('deep' => true));` was the soulution!